# How to get the number of hits of several matching fields in one record?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have records similar to

```
{
    "who": "John",
    "hobby": [
        {"name": "gardening",
         "skills": 2
         },
        {"name": "sleeping",
         "skills": 3
         },
        {"name": "darts",
         "skills": 2
         }
    ]
}
,
{
    "who": "Mary",
    "hobby": [
        {"name": "gardening",
         "skills": 2
         },
        {"name": "volleyball",
         "skills": 3
         },
        {"name": "kung-fu",
         "skills": 2
         }
    ]
}
```

I am looking at building a query which would answer the question: *"how many hobbies with skills=2 do we have?"*

The answer for the example above would be `3` (`"gardening"` is common to both, and each have another unique one).

Every `"query"` or `"query"`+`"aggs"` I tried returns in `['hits']['hits']` or [`'aggregations']['sources']['buckets']` the number of matching **documents**, that is two in the case above (one for `"John"` and one for `"Mary"`, each of them satisfying the query).

**Is there a way to build a query so that it returns the total number of fields (in the example above: the elements of the list `"hobby"`) which matched that query?** (fields, not documents)

Note: If my documents were flat:

```
{"who": "John", "name": "gardening", "skills": 2},
{"who": "John", "name": "sleeping", "skills": 3},
(...)
{"who": "Mary", "name": "kung-fu", "skills": 2}
```

then a simple `"query"` to match "`skills": 2` + an aggregation on `"name"` would have done the work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this with the [`nested` type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-nested-type.html) and using [`inner_hits`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html#nested-inner-hits?q=inner_hits) and/or [`nested` aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html).

So here is the mapping you should use:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/hobbies -d '{
  "mappings": {
    "hob": {
      "properties": {
        "who": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "hobby": {
          "type": "nested",      <--- the hobby list is of type nested
          "properties": {
            "name": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "skills": {
              "type": "integer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then we can insert your two sample documents using the `_bulk` endpoint like this:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/hobbies/hob/_bulk -d '
{"index":{}}
{"who":"John", "hobby":[{"name": "gardening","skills": 2},{"name": "sleeping","skills": 3},{"name": "darts","skills": 2}]}
{"index":{}}
{"who":"Mary", "hobby":[{"name": "gardening","skills": 2},{"name": "volley-ball","skills": 3},{"name": "kung-fu","skills": 2}]}
'
```

And finally, we can query your index for how many hobbies have `skills: 2` like this:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/hobbies/hob/_search -d '{
  "_source": false,
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "hobby",
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "hobby.skills": 2
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {}         <---- this will return only the matching nested fields with skills=2
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "hobbies": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "hobby"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "skills": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "hobby.skills": 2
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "by_field": {         <--- this will return a breakdown of the fields with skills=2
              "terms": {
                "field": "name"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

What this query will return you is

1. In the `hits` part, the four fields that have `skills: 2`
2. In the `aggs` part, a breakdown of the 3 distinct fields which have `skills: 2`

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I was looking at the nested type but somehow missed `inner_hits`